# RPM spec file case update

Tags: yum, rpm

I'm trying create rpm package. Spec file has next macros:

```
%postun
systemctl stop metrics_haproxy.service
systemctl stop checker_haproxy.service
systemctl stop keep_alive.service
systemctl disable metrics_haproxy.service
systemctl disable checker_haproxy.service
systemctl disable keep_alive.service
rm -f /etc/httpd/conf.d/haproxy-wi.conf
rm -f /etc/rsyslog.d/metric.conf
rm -f /etc/rsyslog.d/checker.conf
rm -f /etc/rsyslog.d/keep_alive.conf
rm -f /etc/logrotate.d/metric
rm -f /etc/logrotate.d/checker
rm -f /etc/logrotate.d/keep_alive
systemctl restart rsyslog
systemctl daemon-reload

%post
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart rsyslog
systemctl restart metrics_haproxy.service
systemctl restart checker_haproxy.service
systemctl restart keep_alive.service
systemctl restart httpd
systemctl enable metrics_haproxy.service
systemctl enable checker_haproxy.service
systemctl enable keep_alive.service
systemctl enable httpd
```

but face with one problem: when I update with new version of rpm yum at first creates all services and after deletes. And I'm stay without runned and enabled services after update

There is some workaorund?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read [this page](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/Scriptlets/) to understand the order of script that run upon rpm installation. Most importantly:

1. %post of new package
2. %postun of old package

so the `%postun` script of your old package runs **after** the `%post` script of your new pacakage. What you probably want to do is:

```
%postun
if [ $1 = 0 ]
then
  # the package is really being uninstalled, not upgraded
fi
```

**BUT** since your old package is already installed, the `%postun` script of your old package will still run. So to repair this, I think the easiest solution is to change `%post` in `%posttrans` such that it will run **after** the `%postun` script.

Comment: Thank you, very usefull link

Comment: If your question is solved, please accept the answer to indicate that this solved your question...